# How does Phil Sallee's jpeg toolbox divide images in the coef_arrays?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, jpeg, libjpeg, dct

How does the toolbox divides images into blocks in the coef_arrays?

I have a 225x225 image.
But the coef_arrays gave three 232x232 double arrays.

With a 160x100 image, I get one 104x168 double array and two 56x88 double arrays.

Why am i getting array dimensions more than the image size? 
Am i not supposed to get a total of 225x225 or 160x100 arrays no matter how many blocks the image is divided?

Say 225x225 into 10 blocks would be
11 20x20 arrays and 1 5x5 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG compresses in blocks of 8x8. If you have an image whose size is not a multiple of 8, the encoder has to expand the image to a multiple of 8.

So 225x225 gets expanded into 232x232 with one array for each color component.

For the 160x100 image you are apparently using 2:1 of the Cb and Cr components.

I am not sure why you are getting the sizes you are getting. 160x100 could go to 160x104 (not 168x104) and 80x5o could go to 80x56.

Comment: OK clear on that. I'm using it to perform a DCT on the image. But when it expands the image, wouldnt it change the output? Because what im actually facing is that i have a running matlab code that uses this toolbox to perform dct. And i have another code in JAVA that does the same function. But their outputs are different. JAVA does not expand the image into multiples of 8. So does the expansion changes the output of the DCT?

Comment: It just adds dummy pixels to the data. Plus, the start of frame market includes the original size so the decoders, knows how many dummy pixels there are.